# How to calculate double variable with 10 decimal precision in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm going to calculate double type with 10 decimal point precision. of course, I hope the result precesion has same 10 decimal precision. However, it doesn't work, only 6 decimal point is possible in VS2008. Is there any reason or any idea ?

```
double dMag = 10;
double dPixelSize = 4.4;
double PixelWidth = 1024/2;
double PixelHeight = 768/2;
double umtomm = 1000;

double origin_PosX = 813.227696;
double origin_PosY = 676.195748;

double PosX = (origin_PosX - PixelWidth) * dPixelSize / dMag / umtomm;
double PosY = (origin_PosY - PixelHeight ) * dPixelSize / dMag / umtomm;
```

If I check PosX and PosY, then results are "0.132540, 0.128566" respectively. I expect that results are "0.13254018624000002, 0.12856612912" respectively.

thanks

Comment: How do you "check" the results?  The debugger may not show you the full precision of those numbers.

Comment: Saved the result file. then I checked.

Comment: 'tmp1.Format("%f,%f\r\n", PosX, PosY);
file.Write(tmp1,lstrlen(tmp1));'

Comment: should I use like this "%.17g" instead of "%f" ?

Comment: Or at least %.10f if you want ten digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gather you are confusing a few things...

The precision of `double` is more than just 6 decimal places. I strongly recommend reading [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) which explains how the underlying `double` datatype stores your number and explains its precision.

The precision that is **printed** is limited to 6 decimal places by default. In order to fix that you need to learn how to use the [format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).

In your comments you mentioned using

```
tmp1.Format("%f,%f\r\n", PosX, PosY); file.Write(tmp1,lstrlen(tmp1));
```

to print the strings.

Try changing this line to

```
tmp1.Format("%.10f,%.10f\r\n", PosX, PosY); file.Write(tmp1,lstrlen(tmp1));
```

and you will see that it will print 10 digits after the decimal point.